# SignInWithCredentials with Swift 3 is giving me trouble with Firebase for Facebook login

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift3

I have Facebook login working on its own fine, and the last 2 instructions on the Firebase website are:

```
let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
```

and

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
            // ...
}
```

The first works fine, but the second, Swift says that "signInWithCredential" has now been changed to "signIn", and when I change it to that, it tells me:

> Argument labels '(*:,*:)' do not match any available overloads

Not really sure what to do with:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(credential) { (user, error) in
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It is:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with:credential) { (user, error) in
    // ...
}
```